# Angular: Navigation to the requested Id

Tags: angular, navigateurl

I have a form for adding a name I want to add the user and navigate to the next page with his id.
for example:

[image]

And on the page I get navigation to another page with Url:

```
http://localhost:4200/contact?id=5b07d5ec-627b-45f6-8361-becb9a742d40
```

I have a problem with one line of code:

```
addContact(){

      this.contactsService.GetAllContacts()
    .subscribe(res=> {
        const contact = res.find((a:any)=>{
        return a.displayName === this.contactForm.value.displayName
      });

      if(contact){
        this.contactsService.AddContact(this.contactForm.value)
        .subscribe(() => {
        alert("Signup Succssfull");
        this.contactForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['contact'] , { queryParams: {id: contact?.id}});
  })
 }})
}
```

In this function the problematic line of code is:

```
const contact = res.find((a:any)=>{
return a.displayName === this.contactForm.value.displayName
```

Because I only check if I have such a Name then send it to his URL with the ID
But I do not want an existing user I want a new user I create it as soon as I do ADD get a new ID
I just did not find a suitable function of all the functions

**New Edit**:

Routing:

```
export const routes : Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'login' , component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'help', component:HelpComponent},
  {path:'game', component:GameComponent},
  {path:'app',component:AppComponent},
  {path:'default',component:DefaultLayoutComponent},
  {path:'contact',component:ContactComponent},
  {path:'details',component:DetailsComponent},
  {path:'test',component:TestComponent},
  {path:'addContact',component:AddContactComponent},
  {path:'**' , component:NotFoundComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

NgOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
      params =>{
        const id = params.get('id');
        
        if(id){
          this.contactsService.GetContact(id)
          .subscribe(
            response =>{
              this.contact = response;
            }
          )
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: How does you app-routing.module looks like?

Comment: I added to the post the routing addcontact this is the form in the picture and I want it to navigate to contact by ID

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your app-routing.component.ts like this:

```
  {path:'contact/:id',component:ContactComponent},
```

And in the "parent" component, where you press the button make something like this:

```
   <button [routerLink]="['/contact', contact.id]">Add </button>
```

and then in the contactComponent.ts in the beginning of the NgOnInit() {} write this:

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Something like this.. Look at the dynamic routing. Its hard to perfectly write working solution without demo.
If you have time, make StackBlitz demo for us

Comment: I'll try what you said

Comment: I did not understand where to put it
**this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get ('id');**
In my code

Comment: Can you explain to me how I put this line of code into the code? I can not understand

Comment: Does your code successfuly re-route you to the next page with specific info? You put this in the beginning of the NgOnInit so you can fetch the ID from te url and then re-use the specific ID

Comment: I forgot to add my NGONINIT, I will now show you it in the POST

Comment: I added you can look

Comment: I get id null
And my URL is
contact / null

Comment: Please create stackblitz duplicate